# How to delete almost "identical" line features?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have almost identical lines with the same attributes, but the lengths are slightly different (for instance 0.01m) how to find and delete them? I've tried "topology check" and "select by location" but it didn't work...

Comment: Use the [Delete duplicates by attribute](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicates-by-attribute) tool.

Comment: Doesn't work. I think because they are not exactly geometrically duplicates (length tolerance is +- 0.01m) but the other attribute values are the same.

Comment: This does not deal with geometries, as it name says it removes feature with the same attributes. I suggested you this because you said that your features had the same attributes.

Answer (score 1):

"Almost identical" is subjective much.
Make buffer polygons around your linear objects. As you wrote the diference is about 0.01, then buffer width have to be close to 0.01. Calc intersections between buffers. If ratio of intersection area to original buffer area for both objects is more then 0.9 (try it with different values) then objects may be identical.