# Selecting unclassified road line (One layer) that miss survey data (another layer)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, intersect, symmetric-difference

I am working on QGIS 3.10. My goal is to select all the Unclassified road that do not have any scheme.  For that I need to overlap the two layers (Unclassified road network and schemes) together in order to use the select by location tool.

I tried the intersect tool and the symmetrical difference but no success.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details on your data.

Comment: I use the unclassified road network and a scheme layer. Both layers have multiple part. I merged the unclassified rd network and split it so the parts are similar than the scheme layer. Some of the scheme are overlapping on the unclassified layer. Other parts are not touching the unclassified network.

Comment: The problem seems similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436335/how-to-delete-almost-identical-line-features/436504#436504